# javascript how to use make process wait until async function finishes

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

now I'm making a user Authentication system, but I'm having trouble with javascript's process order. Here is my code.

```
const isAuthenticated = async (username, password) => {
//this User.finOne is async function
        User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, foundUser) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            if (foundUser) {
                if (foundUser.password === password) {
                    console.log("ID:", foundUser.id);
                    console.log("NAME:", foundUser.username);
                    return foundUser.id
                }
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    });
}

app.post("/login", async function (req, res) {
    const userName = req.body.username;
    const password = md5(req.body.password);

    let userID = await isAuthenticated(userName, password);
    
    // userID becomes undefined
    console.log("userID", userID);

    if (userID === 0 || userID == undefined) {
        const status = 401
        const message = 'Incorrect username or password'
        res.status(status).json({ status, message })
        return
    }

    const accessToken = createToken({ id: isAuthenticated(userName, password) })
    console.log("here is token", accessToken);

    const responseJson = {
        success: true,
        username: userName,
        userID: userID
    }

    res.cookie('JWTcookie', accessToken, { httpOnly: true })
    res.status(200).json(responseJson)
```

When a user logged in with a correct password and username, this API is supposed to return cookie. This cookie itself works fine, but the problem is that " if (userID === 0 || userID == undefined)" is processed earlier than the function isAuthenticated().
When I checked the order, isAuthenticated is processed later. To prevent this, I tried using async await, so that the job stops at let userID = await isAuthenticated(userName, password);. But this didn't work.

If anyone point out why this programming is working in this order, I really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be `isAuthenticated` isn't waiting for anything to finish execution from within itself even though it has been declared `async`. Hence even if you are doing this: `let userID = await isAuthenticated(userName, password);`, since   isAuthenticated isnt returning or awaiting a Promise / any asynchronous activity inside it, the compiler would just move on and continue executing the remaining piece of code in that function.
If you want the `User.findOne` function to be executed first you should be changing the isAuthenticated function to something similar to this:

```
const isAuthenticated = async (username, password) => {
        await User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, foundUser) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            if (foundUser) {
                if (foundUser.password === password) {
                    console.log("ID:", foundUser.id);
                    console.log("NAME:", foundUser.username);
                    return foundUser.id
                }
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    });
}
```